# .serialize() not consistant in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the `serialize()` function to grab all fields in a form. In rare cases, customers call saying that after they save the cart only one item is left. After investigating, it turns out that for some users the `serialize()` function is only submitting the last item array named `items[ITEMNUM] = qty`.

**HTML :**

```
<form id="cartitems" action="self">
    <table width="98%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td style=" font-size:.9em;">title</td>
            <td width="30"> <input name="items[AH33.3600]" class="qty" value="1" /></td>
            <td width="30" nowrap="nowrap" style="padding-right:10px; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;">Total</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style=" font-size:.9em;">title</td>
            <td width="30"> <input name="items[PNP-A00SVR30]" class="qty" value="1" /></td>
            <td width="30" nowrap="nowrap" style="padding-right:10px; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;">Total</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style=" font-size:.9em;">title</td>
            <td width="30"> <input name="items[A4882+++++107+5X12]" class="qty" value="1" /></td>
            <td width="30" nowrap="nowrap" style="padding-right:10px; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;">Total</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
var subform = $("#cartitems").serialize();
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function() {        
        $('#cartitems').slideUp().queue(function() {
            $(this).dequeue();
            $('#cartitems').html(' Please wait...  Cart Loading').show();
        });
    },
    url: "/order/ajax/cart",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data:  subform,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(html){
        alert('info saved');
    }
});
```

The latest customer I spoke to was using Firefox 7.

Does anyone see a problem?

Comment: I only see one input in the cart items form, how many should there be?

Comment: sorry that row tag is in a foreach().  The number varies but the customers with issue have more than one.  Sometimes only one-two items will make it, and the rest are dropped.

Comment: Helps to show what the markup is without the severside code. Aka copy the markup from view source/debugger.

Comment: @epascarello I have added the final output instead of the foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this in several browsers and it seemed to work ok - http://jsfiddle.net/z6P4x/

Comment: yeah that is what I thought too.  But it seems like some odd browser version, only grab the last input in my array.  I haven't been able to replicate but it is happening for customers using older browsers.  I also wonder if it's the urlencode() being used to encode the item number in the array.

Comment: I seem to have mitigated the problem by looking for a hidden field at the bottom of the form.  If it's not submitted then I give the user a error.  This seemed to have solved 95% of the users complaints.  I will mark this as a answer for your time.